# Are voice, text and data shared the same channel in 2G, 3G and 4G networks?

Tags: communication, telecommunications

Are voice, text and data transmitted in a shared channel in 2G (e.g. GSM), 3G (e.g. CDMA) and 4G (e.g. LTE, WiMAX) networks?

In what networks, are they shared? In what networks, are they not?

Btw, if I am correct, time dividing and frequency dividing are both used for implementing sharing a channel.

Thanks.

Comment: SMS on GSM uses SS7 MAP, a data channel not used for mobile data, and separate from the voice channels. Basically a side band.

Answer (score 1):

2G networks handle voice and data separately. Voice is on the TCH traffic channel. GPRS data on PDTCH. SMS isn't really treated as either, and is on the SDCCH control channel.

3G voice and data are both on DCH/DTCH, but using different quality of service classes. Or for HSPA, HS-DSCH and E-DCH.

LTE and VoLTE both use PDSCH/PUSCH, but there are some new scheduling options for volte like semi-persistent scheduling and packet aggregation.

Comment: if there's any mistakes here feel free to edit! I used to think it was crazy the way people would throw around 5-letter-acronyms in the office, I find it too easy to get them mixed up.